# Spring 4.3 Framework: Deadlock on ConcurrentHashMap AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean

Tags: spring

Scenario - Looks like this is timing issue. We have application lock (Lock#1) before calling getBean(), then there comes Spring framework ConcurrentHashMap (Lock#2). Threads are getting blocked on Lock#1 and Lock#2.  Please find below snippets of thread dumps to prove the use case.

**T1 - (Acquired Lock#1 and waiting for Lock#2)**

"Catalina-utility-1" #85 prio=1 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9918034000 nid=0x33f0 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f97f1ccd000]

java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)

```
          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:213)

          - waiting to lock <0x00000004df51aef8> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)   (-> At this place, waiting for Spring lock, Lock#2. Here it has already acquired Lock#1, and waiting for Lock#2 )

          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)

          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)

          at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1082)

          at com.bmc.unifiedadmin.service.ABCServiceBeanContext.getService(ABCServiceBeanContext.java:53)

          at com.bmc.unifiedadmin.service.ABCServicesFactory.getService(ABCServicesFactory.java:52)     (**-> At this place, application semaphore have been acquired, Lock#1**)
```

**T2 - (Acquired Lock#2 and waiting for Lock#1)**

```
          at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:312) -> (**At this place, waiting for TSPS lock, Lock#1. Here it has already acquired Lock#2, and waiting for Lock#2**)

    —

    –

          at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

          at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

          at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

          at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)

          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)

          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1151)

          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)

          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)

          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)

          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)

          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)

          - locked <0x00000004df51aef8> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)   (**-> At this place, Lock#2 has been acquired**)
```

Comment: Why are yu using the application context to get a bean? YOu shouldn't be doing that but rather use dependency injection.

Comment: Hi, Deinum. This is legacy code. I am wondering if Spring has come up with any improvements for such situations. I could see couple of issue already logged on similar use cases.         https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/383, https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7718,  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/13117

Comment: The point is, regardless if this is legacy code or not, it is the wrong way to get a bean. You shouldn't be doing this and rewrite it to use proper dependency injection (or just simply bean construction).

Comment: That's not a point, rather that's a different point, eventually, we will have to do that. Here questions is from spring library perspective, if any improvement for such use cases in upcoming release, or any fix in existing release or not fix at all -this is not a bug kind of information I am looking for.

Comment: So the fact that you wrongly use a framework is a bug in the framework? Also how is linking to a Spring Cloud (not Spring Framework issue) related to this? Nonentheless have you tried upgrading to the latest 4.3 release (which is the last supported version and you really should upgrade to 5.x). It also appears as if you implemented your own `ApplicationContext` looking at the hierarchy, which is part of the issue imho.

Comment: Looks like you are making assumptions without reading it properly. And your assumptions are wrong. Nowhere I am saying its bug in framework, I am just looking for information from spring framework perspective. - Check my comment above (-this is not a bug kind of information I am looking for).

Comment: I'm not assuming anything I'm deducing things from your stacks, which clearly state you have implemented something on top of Spring and I wonder why. I don't get the locking you are talking about. The only thing you have is a half description and 2 thread dumps. So the only thing we can do is try to fill in the blanks. Post the code that is, according to you, an issue. And as stated linking a Spirng Cloud issue to this isn't helping either.

Comment: I am running into a similar issue. I agree with @RakeshVende , although it's not an explicit bug in the framework, it is clearly something that makes easier to shoot yourself in the foot. A lot of places do getBean instead of autowiring and I am seeing countless issues related to these specific locks